# Cannot detect Xperia C in ADT and Android Studio installed in Windows 8.1 PC

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, sony-xperia

I have a Sony Xperia C2305 with Android version 4.2.2. Problem is I cannot deploy, debug and test android app within it. Neither Eclipse ADT nor Android Studio detect this phone. I found this phone detects on Windows 7 but I am using Windows 8.1.

How can I solve this detection problem? I also visited the Sony sites for driver, but I could not find any driver for this phone. Besides that I think all other relevant settings are OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I know how to fix your problem. Open **"my computer" -> device manager -> other devices -> Android -> right click and choose update driver**. **Browse my computer for Driver Software -> Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer.** Then scroll down and find **Sony so0101 driver**.

If you haven't this driver in list, you should install it from http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=50386981&postcount=5 this attachment. Just unzip and run DPInst64 (don't forget to set compatibility with windows vista sp2). 
After that you can choose sony so0101 driver.

It works for my **Sony Xperia M2** on windows 8.1

Comment: That's great man, spot on. Thank you so much. I followed your first paragraph of you. In my case, I chose Sony so0106 and it worked successfully. Big relief for me. I didn't have to use the zip file from the given link.

Comment: You're welcome) In my case the correct driver was not in the list, that's why I added link.

Answer (score 1):

Have you opened the Developer options in the system Settings?
On Android 4.2 and higher, the Developer options screen is hidden by default. To make it visible, go to Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven times. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options at the bottom.

Comment: Possibly the silliest thing I've ever seen.  But it worked.  Still silly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already downloaded the Android SDK? If not, install & open it, select "Google USB Driver" in the Extras tab, maybe deselect all the other stuff you don't need, and click "Install Packages"

Also you have to enable "USB Debugging" in the developer options. @ivkil explained how.

EDIT: It seems that he deleted his Answer (it vanished...).

Enable Developer Options: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

EDIT 2: nevermind.

Comment: I have android sdk installed. Google USB Driver rev.11 installed. USB debugging enabled.